# TFS2010: Build Definition for projects under multiple Team Projects

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a Visual Studio Solution having 3 projects in it. Same solution is having a folder in which I added existing projects which belong to other TFS Team Project.

```
TeamPrj1
|- Solution1
 |- External Reference(folder)
 |- PrjA (added as existing project) 
 |- Prj1
 |- Prj2
TeamPrj2
|- SolutionA
 |- PrjA
```

I want to have a TFS Build for my Solution1. The problem I am facing is that the solution is not compiling on the TFS Build Server as it cannot find the reference of the PrjA. I know there is some tweak to be done in the workspace mapping and I went through [different forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/f33bdfad-b868-40d9-a447-21beb70754c5) and blogpost too but still doesn't work. Some say to add the PrjA dll as a file reference but I dont want to go that route as what if something changes in PrjA than the Sol1 needs to be re-reference the latest dll. Having added as reference, it automatically gets the latest everytime Solution1 is opened from TFS.

Currently below is my workspace mapping.

```
 Active $/TeamPrj1/Main/Solution1
 $(SourceDir)

 Active $/TeamPrjA/Main/SolutionA
 $(SouceDir)\Main\
```

Comment: In your solution file in Solution 1, what is the relative path to the ProjA .csproj? This needs to match your workspace setup. You might need to open Solution 1.sln in notepad to figure this out.

Comment: You shouldn't need notepad Jesse, look at the properties on the reference in the solution explorer and you will see the resolved relative path, that should give you enough info to know the relative.

Comment: @Alex I want to see the actual solution file contents. Visual Studio tends to add an absolute path to project files outside of the solution's root folder.

Comment: Jesse, it doesn't show you an absolute path, it shows a locally resolved relative path. But, either way works, calculating the relative path in your head or open the soltuion file in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Visual Studio project, for example a team project containing shared library code that is used by multiple team projects,

- You can either manage the project within the owning team’s project or
  you can create a separate team project specifically for the shared
  project.
- If you choose the latter approach and use a common shared project,
  the folder structure in Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation
  Server (TFS) source control looks like

[image]

For more info see the following:

[Chapter 6 – Managing Source Control Dependencies in Visual Studio Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668956.aspx)

Comment: Branching a particular project from a TeamProject into another is not a problem but what if there are many TeamProjects using the same Common project. You will have to branch same project into so many branches. And for instance a single line of code changes in the Main branch, a developer needs to manually do a merge to all this child branches and check it in? If this Merge process can be automated, then branching is I guess the best solution but if changes have to be manually pushed than its very cumbersome process. Any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution needs to reference the other project using a relative path, you need to make sure that the Workspace mapping for the Build Definition actually results in the same file structure as on your local workspace.

Judging from your folder names, you should use the following mapping:

```
 Active | $/TeamProj1/Main/Solution1 | $(Sourcedir)\Solution1
 Active | $/TeamProjA/Main/SolutionA | $(Sourcedir)\SolutionA
```

But I cannot be sure of the exact target paths until we know the relative path defined to `PrjA.csproj` in `Solution1.sln`.

You will probably need to update the path to the solution in the Process Tab of the Build Definition editor as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best option is to have a enterprise NuGet server and publish packages this NuGet site internally.

For visual studio solutions under different Team Projects, they can easily NuGet for referencing. The TFS Automated build can also easily restore NuGet packages for any solution.

You can also have the automated builds to drop a NuGet package to NuGet server for the assemblies/exe's which are common across multiple TeamProject and Team Collections also. (xcopy command in build template).

**The biggest benefit of using this approach:** Everything is automated. No need to do any manual merge and checkin. Can be used across multiple TeamProject & TeamCollections. If a parent common dll changes, the automated build for it can push it to NuGet server. Next time all other project using the common dll via NuGet will have always the latest one as on the Build Server it will always download the latest from NuGet (assumption that you keep the version # same).